# ZODB not able to commit

Tags: python, zodb

I am using ZODB first time. Just trying to commit the data with FileStorage. But when I do the same script second time I am not able to commit the new object. Here is my script

```
from ZODB import FileStorage,DB
import transaction    
storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('/tmp/test.fs')
db = DB(storage)
conn = db.open()
root = conn.root()
#root['layer']={}
root['layer']['2b']={"id":'2b','name':'some name'}
transaction.commit()
conn.close()
db.close()
storage.close()
```

when I repeat the code once again, with just changing the id `root['layer']['2c']` and come out of the python, the second time object is not getting committed. I only have first object only. What could be the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ZODB persistence layer detects changes by hooking into the python `__setattr__` hook, marking the persistent object as changed every time you set an attribute.

But if you use a primitive mutable object like a python dictionary, then there is no way for the persistence machinery to detect the changes, as there is no attribute being written. You have three options to work around this:

### Use a persistent mapping

The persistent package includes a persistent mapping class, which is basically a python dictionary implementation that is persistent and detects changes directly by hooking into `__setitem__` and other mapping hooks. The `root` object in your example is basically a persistent mapping.

To use, just replace all dictionaries with persistent mappings:

```
from persistent.mapping import PersistentMapping
root['layer'] = PersistentMapping()
```

### Force a change detection by triggering the hook

You could just set the key again, or on a persistent object, set the attribute again to force the object to be changed:

```
root['layer'] = root['layer']
```

### Flag the persistent object as changed

You can set the `_p_changed` flag on the nearest persistent object. Your root object is the only persistent object you have, everything else is python dictionaries, so you need to flag that as changed:

```
root._p_changed = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Martin,  by setting _p_changed=1, I am am able to store the new dictionary object. I'll go through the PersistentMapping also.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing an

```
root['layer']._p_changed = 1
```

after modifiying the dict.

http://zodb.org/documentation/guide/prog-zodb.html?highlight=_p_changed#modifying-mutable-objects