# Writing and reading a dictionary in specific format (Python)

Tags: python, file, loops, dictionary

Sorry another newbie query :| To build upon the suggestion which was given here,
 [optimizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221573/how-to-optimize-the-memory-and-time-usage-of-the-following-algorithm-in-python)

I need to be able to incrementally build a dictionary i.e. one key: value at a time inside a for loop. To be specific, the dictionary would look something like (N keys, with each value being a list of lists. The smaller inner list has 3 elements):

```
dic_score ={key1:[ [,,], [,,], [,,] ...[,,] ], key2:[ [,,], [,,], [,,] ..[,,] ] ..keyN:[[,,], [,,], [,,] ..[,,]]}
```

This dic is being generated from the following paradigm, a nested for loop.

```
for Gnodes in G.nodes()       # Gnodes iterates over 10000 values 
    Gvalue = someoperation(Gnodes)
    for Hnodes in H.nodes()   # Hnodes iterates over 10000 values 
        Hvalue =someoperation(Hnodes)
        score = SomeOperation on (Gvalue,Hvalue)
        dic_score.setdefault(Gnodes,[]).append([Hnodes, score, -1 ])
```

I then need to sort these lists, but the answer for that was given here,  [optimizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221573/how-to-optimize-the-memory-and-time-usage-of-the-following-algorithm-in-python) (use of generator expression in place of the inner loop is an option)
[Note that the dic would contain 10000 keys with each key associated with a 10000 elements of smaller lists]

Since the loop counters are big, the dictionary generated is huge and I am running out of memory.

How can I **write** the write the Key:value (a list of lists) as soon as it is generated to a file, so that I don't need to hold the entire dictionary in memory. I then want to be able to **read** back the dictionary in the same format i.e. something like dic_score_after_reading[key], returns me the list of list I am looking for.

I am hopping that doing this writing and reading per key:value would considerably ease the memory requirements. Is there a better data structure to do this? Shall I be considering a database , probably like Buzhug, which would give me the flexibility to access and iterate over lists associated with each key ?

I am currently using **cPickle** to dump the entire dictionary and then reading it back via load(), but cPickle crashes while dumping such a big data in one go.

Apologies, but I am unaware of the best practices to do this type of stuff. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using the [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/) in combination with the included [`BTrees`](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/modules.html#btrees-package) implementation.

What that gives is a mapping-like structure that writes individual entries separately to the object store. You'd need to use [savepoints](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/transactions.html#subtransactions) or plain [transactions](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/transactions.html#transactions-and-versioning) to flush data out to the storage, but you can handle huge amounts of data this way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! Let me digg into this as I am not aware on how these work.

Comment: @Martjin : I tried to implement the ZODB in combination with Btree, as u suggested, but I am running into a small issue. When I open the database for reading , I find that some of the records are missing. Specifically, as  mentioned above I store my dic. in the form of a Btree and attach it to the root. Btree contains say 20 keys with each key corresponding to list of list ( as written in the original question ). However, some list elements go missing when I open the data base again , after having closed it once. I am using transaction.commit() after every time I append to the key.

Comment: in the inner loop, after every iteration,I do btree.setdefault(key,[]).append([ref_node, score, -1]) ; transaction.commit() , so that the list associated with each key build incrementally. I see the full list when I am done, but it's when I reopen that I find missing elements in the list of list[refer original post]. Any ideas/suggestions as to what might be going wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ah, you use lists; these are mutable and the ZODB doesn't notice the changes and won't commit those. See [ZODB not able to commit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5704589) , http://zodb.org/documentation/guide/prog-zodb.html#rules-for-writing-persistent-classes, http://zodb.org/documentation/articles/ZODB1.html#mutable-attributes, and http://zodb.org/documentation/guide/modules.html#PersistentList.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I introduced the command `root[0]._p_changed = 1` before `transaction.commit()`, which worked when I had small number of keys ( 20-30). As I jumped to more keys, >100, again I am observing the same issue, that in some of the keys , some list elements are missing. Any other suggestion as to whats going on here ?

Comment: The BTree uses buckets, which are themselves persistent, when you get to more items. You'd have to call `_p_changed` on those, but that'll be tricky. Use presistent lists or reassignment (instead of .append) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot !declaring the lists that I was storing in Btree as PersistentList did it for me ! I had couple couple more newbie questions and would be glad if you could provide some insights on them. I am currently commiting() only after both my loops have completely run and the entire btree is ready. As I understand nothing will be written to the DB unless I do the commit. Does that mean that everything is still stored in RAM. In that case will is end up with the same problem of storing huge dictionary in RAM ? (2) How fast the process can be if I just write everything on a .txt file ?

Comment: You know, we are really straining the SO format here. You should really make those questions into new SO questions. That way others can help out too. :-)

Comment: I agree :-) ! Thanks a lot for your guidance !